# Could not read from remote repository while updating repository in bitbucket

Tags: git, bitbucket

I have cloned repository in bitbucket. Now I need to synchronize it after source repository has been updated. I'm clicking sync button on the right side of "Source" panel. Then it says that there are too many conflicts and they can not be resolved in the web interface:

[image]

I try to follow the instruction, but I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Stepan\Projects\test>git checkout master
Already on 'master'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

C:\Users\Stepan\Projects\test>git remote add someuser/somerepo git@bitbucket.org:someuser/somerepo.git

C:\Users\Stepan\Projects\test>git fetch someuser/ow
git@bitbucket.org: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Repository owner says he has granted me all access rights. How can I fix that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The instruction bitbucket gives, is wrong, after **git remote add ...**, I had to edit url property in **.git/config** manually:

git@bitbucket.org:someuser/somerepo.git -> https://stepany@bitbucket.org/someuser/somerepo.git